# Ruby RegEx/pattern-match for exact word/string matching

Tags: ruby, regex, erb

Got a quick question: I have a file like this:

```
ip-10-0-12-84.eu-west-1.compute.internal, master, instnum=1, Running
.....
.....
ip-10-0-26-118.eu-west-1.compute.internal, master_rabbit, instnum=4, Running
ip-10-0-26-116.eu-west-1.compute.internal, master_rabbit, instnum=5, Running
.....
ip-10-0-26-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal, sql_master, instnum=9, Running
ip-10-0-13-244.eu-west-1.compute.internal, nat, instnum=2, Running
```

My goal is to read the file, skipping comments (starts with `#`), empty/blank lines and the lines with `nat` or `master` in it. I tried this:

```
open('/tmp/runnings.txt').each do |line|
    next if line =~ /(^\s*(#|$)|nat|master)/
```

which is almost working but it also eliminates the lines with `master_rabbit` and `sql_master` in it. How can I pick only `master` and not the any other combination of that? Can it done in the same line? Cheers!!

Comment: Search for ', master,' instead of just 'master' :)

Comment: Does the same go for `nat`, as well? Or would you want to match `national`, too?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: at moment there is no need for `national` but it's a good point. Your ans covers that.

Comment: @MacUsers Tim is asking a question. It is not a good or a bad point. What is your answer?

Comment: @sawa: Well, as I already said: it's not really required at the moment, but maybe in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) can help here:

```
/^\s*(#|$)|\b(nat|master)\b/
```

Comment: thanks Tim, that's exactly what I needed; did the job nicely. I knew there is an easier-than-I-think way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
open("/tmp/runnings.txt").each_line
.grep(/\A(?!\s*#)(?!.*\bnat\b)(?!.*\bmaster\b).*\S/) do |line|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is not a place where the problem should be solved with a regexp. Sure you can get one to work for now, but it will be hard to understand later and harder to edit if you get new keywords to exclude.

I like this way of solving the problem:

```
FILE_PATH = '/tmp/runnings.txt'
keywords  = ['nat', 'master']
empty_lines_and_comments     = ->x{ x.chomp.empty? or x.start_with?('#') }
lines_containing_bad_keyword = ->x{ keywords.include? x[1] } # Keywords at index 1

data = File.readlines(FILE_PATH)
           .reject(&empty_lines_and_comments)
           .map{|line| line.chomp.split(', ')}
           .reject(&lines_containing_bad_keyword)
```

Comment: considering the very static nature of the file (in question) I don't think there is any need for any additional keyword(s) at the moment but it always good to know the right way of doing certain things. Thanks for the code; I definitely have some use fpr it. Cheers!!